# Align centered components

Tags: html, css

I don't know much CSS and I am facing the following problem:

I have some elements in a div like below and I want to **align them**. (make them all start from the same x coordinate). I also want to keep them in the middle of the page.

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users | async; index as userId">
  <h3>
    <span><img [src]="user.avatar" class="e-avatar"></span>
    <a [title]="user.username" [routerLink]="['/messagewindow', usercurrentId, userId+1]">
      {{ user.username }}
    </a>
  </h3>
</div>
```

For now, they are centered like this:

[image]

The page looks like:
[image]

Comment: so right now, there seems to be text-align: center; called on them. is that necessary or can you just switch to text-align: left; and maybe add some padding where needed?

Comment: I want them to be centered on the page, but at the same time aligned. I will add a photo with the whole look of the page, maybe it helps.

Comment: you could wrap them in a wrapper element that is only as wide it's content (with sth like display: inline-block; oder width: max-content;) and center that, while setting the elements alignment to text-align: left;
But depending on the length of some of the names, it will not look optically centered – that's just in the nature of this design.

Answer (score 1):

**If your users div is already at center then you can remove the height:100vh and align-items: center property.**

```css
.main-div{
 display: flex;
 height:100vh;
 width: 100%;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center
}

.avatar {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div  class="main-div" *ngFor="let user of users | async; index as userId">
  <h3 class="avatar">
    <span><img [src]="user.avatar" class="e-avatar"></span>
    <a [title]="user.username" [routerLink]="['/messagewindow', usercurrentId, userId+1]">
      {{ user.username }}
    </a>
  </h3>
</div>
```